# CodeIgniter Ion Auth - Incorrect Login

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

Using Ion Auth, I was able to successfully register and activate an account. The created account shows up in the database. However, trying to login keeps on saying "Incorrect Login." I have tried various combinations of passwords, tried enabling separately stored salt, changed to bcrypt, etc to no avail. The odd thing is that the default admin credentials login fine.

```
function testlogin()
{
    // ADMIN LOGIN
    if ($this->ion_auth->login("admin@admin.com", "password", false))
    {
        echo "Admin login successful <br/>";
        $this->ion_auth->logout();
    }
    else
        echo "Admin login failed";

    // MEMBER LOGIN
    if ($this->ion_auth->login("example@example.com", "pwhere", false))
    {
        echo "Member login successful";
        $this->ion_auth->logout();
    }
    else
        echo "Member login failed";
}
```

The above function prints:

```
Admin login successful 
Member login failed
```

Is there anything else that needs to be done after registering and activating the account?

Comment: The login data is stored in sessions, so I doubt that it's possible to log a user in, log out, then log another user in the same request. Try to separate the tests into 2 methods, and call each one in separate requests. You can test that by just commenting out the whole 'admin login' `if` loop; you should then simply get `Member login successful`.

Comment: remove the logout function and check

Answer (score 2):

@froddd is correct, in order for CodeIgniter's session library to handle this properly you need a redirect after everything login() and logout() call.